# Is "올림픽 겨울 게임" a correct/natural way to say "Winter Olympics"?

Tags: translation

[image: BBC]

I noticed some of the BBC's coverage of the Winter Olympics is calling them "올림픽 겨울 게임".

A Korean friend remarked that this sounded a bit awkward, and that 동계올림픽 was more normal, as per the title of the official site: [평창동계올림픽](https://www.pyeongchang2018.com/ko/index).

Nevertheless, could "올림픽 겨울 게임" be considered correct? Or is it a mistake arising from literally translating "Olympic Winter Games" word-by-word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend is right. 
Korean call "The Winter Olympics", "동계 올림픽".
(동계 means 'winter(동) season(계)').
I think '올림픽 겨울 게임' is just translated by word-by-word.

Comment: In fact, 올림픽 겨울 게임 is the Google translation of winter olympic games.

Comment: @gaeguri strange, as the BBC maintains a [whole Korean site](https://www.bbc.com/korean)  - you'd think they'd be able to afford a human translator for one sentence!